# Console table format in ruby

Tags: ruby, console

Is there a way to output an array of arrays as a table in ruby? I'm looking for something that is useful from the console, like powershell's `format-table` command.

An array that would be passed could be something like:

```
a = [[1.23, 5, :bagels], [3.14, 7, :gravel], [8.33, 11, :saturn]]
```

And the output could be something like:

```
-----------------------
| 1.23 |  5 | bagels  |
| 3.14 |  7 | gravel  |
| 8.33 | 11 | saturn  |
-----------------------
```

Comment: http://tableprintgem.com/

Comment: you can also have a look at [gem 'awesome-print'](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print), here is it's [example for rails console](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print#example-rails-console) not exactly table format but in well formatted pattern

Comment: @JLB Doesn't look like the author(s) take much pride in their work. The monospace formatting on that page doesn't work.

Comment: Also https://github.com/tj/terminal-table

Comment: @Fuser97381 can you add  your array to your question?

Comment: @SachinSingh I've added an example. I was hoping there was a gem-free solution for this but I guess it's a lot to ask. Just because powershell does, doesn't mean ruby should. PHP and Javascript don't.

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are a number of solutions that provide this, from ORMs when retrieving data from a database, to plugins for IRB and gems that work with the command-line, however it's off-topic to ask for recommendations. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
a = [[1.23, 5, :bagels], [3.14, 7, :gravel], [8.33, 11, :saturn]]

bar = '-'*(a[0][0].to_s.length + 4 + a[0][1].to_s.length + 3 + a[0][2].to_s.length + 4) 

puts bar
a.each do |i|
  i.each.with_index do |j,k|
    if k == 1 && j < 10
      print "|  #{j} "
    else
      print "| #{j} "
    end
  end
  print '|'
  puts
end
puts bar
```

*returns:*

```
----------------------
| 1.23 |  5 | bagels |
| 3.14 |  7 | gravel |
| 8.33 | 11 | saturn |
----------------------
```

`bar` is just an estimate of how long the top and bottom dash-bar will be. In general this code checks each sub-array and prints out its elements with `|` in the appropriate places. The only tricky bit is the second element of each sub-array. Here we check to see if it is double digit or single digit. The print-format is different for each.

Bear in mind that this code works specifically for your example and makes a lot of assumptions. Having said that it can be easily modified to taste.

Answer (score 7):

I accepted sagarpandya82's answer, but here's my better implementation:

```
class Array
  def to_table
    column_sizes = self.reduce([]) do |lengths, row|
      row.each_with_index.map{|iterand, index| [lengths[index] || 0, iterand.to_s.length].max}
    end
    puts head = '-' * (column_sizes.inject(&:+) + (3 * column_sizes.count) + 1)
    self.each do |row|
      row = row.fill(nil, row.size..(column_sizes.size - 1))
      row = row.each_with_index.map{|v, i| v = v.to_s + ' ' * (column_sizes[i] - v.to_s.length)}
      puts '| ' + row.join(' | ') + ' |'
    end
    puts head
  end
end
```

Comment: +1. Nice solution. My answer is really inferior to yours so you really should accept your own answer instead!

Comment: @sagarpandya82 It's considered rude in my culture to accept your own answer.

Comment: The line padding out each item in the row with spaces could be simplified by using `ljust`: `v.to_s.ljust(column_sizes[i], ' ')` (which would also make it easier to modify to right aligned by switching to `rjust`).

Answer (score 0):

I've made a small improvement on the @dart-egregious snippet

```rb
class Array
  def to_table(header: true)
    column_sizes = self.reduce([]) do |lengths, row|
      row.each_with_index.map{|iterand, index| [lengths[index] || 0, iterand.to_s.length].max}
    end
    head = '+' + column_sizes.map{|column_size| '-' * (column_size + 2) }.join('+') + '+'
    puts head

    to_print = self.clone
    if (header == true)
      header = to_print.shift
      print_table_data_row(column_sizes, header)
      puts head
    end
    to_print.each{ |row| print_table_data_row(column_sizes, row) }
    puts head
  end

  private
  def print_table_data_row(column_sizes, row)
    row = row.fill(nil, row.size..(column_sizes.size - 1))
    row = row.each_with_index.map{|v, i| v = v.to_s + ' ' * (column_sizes[i] - v.to_s.length)}
    puts '| ' + row.join(' | ') + ' |'
  end
end
```

Using:

```rb
data = [
  ['column 1', 'column 2', 'ciolumn 3'],
  ['row 1 col 2', 'row 1 col 2', 'row 1 col 3'],
  ['row 1 col 2', 'row 1 col 2', 'row 1 col 3']
]

data.to_table
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| column 1    | column 2    | ciolumn 3   |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| row 1 col 2 | row 1 col 2 | row 1 col 3 |
| row 1 col 2 | row 1 col 2 | row 1 col 3 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+


data.to_table(header: false)
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| column 1    | column 2    | ciolumn 3   |
| row 1 col 2 | row 1 col 2 | row 1 col 3 |
| row 1 col 2 | row 1 col 2 | row 1 col 3 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```